# I want to hover over a div and show a pseudo element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that has an `:after` psuedo element I want to be able to hover on the div and then the `:after` element is shown

HTML

```
<div class="about-us_creative-technology_top-box">
                <div class="about-us_creative-technology_h1">
                        <h1>Creative<br>Technology</h1>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Mobile and Web Application Development</li>
                        <li>Product Development</li>
                        <li>Software Development and Management</li>
                        <li>Architecture and Design</li>
                        <li>Cloud Management, Strategy and Management</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="about-us_creative-technology_square">

            </div>
```

CSS

```
&_top-box{
        height: 25vw;
        position: relative;
        &:hover + &:after{
            display: block;
        }
        &:after {
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            border: solid transparent;
            content: " ";
            height: 0;
            width: 0;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
            border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            border-top-color: #F2F2F2;
            border-width: 25px;
            margin-left: -25px;
            z-index: 2;
            display: none;
        }
```

Now ive tried using `&:hover + &:after{
                         display: block;
                     }`

but I cant seem to get it to work, does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You didn't ask a question or describe the problem you're having.

Comment: @Amy see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. It is saying it is a next sibling and it is not.

&:hover + &:after{

Get rid of that and just do

```
    &:hover::after {
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        border: solid transparent;
        content: " ";
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
        border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
        border-top-color: #F2F2F2;
        border-width: 25px;
        margin-left: -25px;
        z-index: 2;
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: THANKYOU! Ive been stuck on this for ages, I even tried accessing it using javascript and that wasnt working either! you sir are a genius

Comment: I have another question if you dont mind, that totally works but when I move my cursor to `about-us_creative-technology_square` div it dissapears Im aware that they are two different divs how can I make it that when I hover on that div aswell the arrow is there?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```css
.about-us_creative-technology_top-box{
height: 25vw;
position: relative;
}
.about-us_creative-technology_top-box:hover::after{
display: block;
}
.about-us_creative-technology_top-box::after {
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
border: solid transparent;
content: " ";
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
border-top-color: #F2F2F2;
border-width: 25px;
margin-left: -25px;
z-index: 2;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-us_creative-technology_top-box">
<div class="about-us_creative-technology_h1">
<h1>Creative<br>Technology</h1>
</div>
<ul>
<li>Mobile and Web Application Development</li>
<li>Product Development</li>
<li>Software Development and Management</li>
<li>Architecture and Design</li>
<li>Cloud Management, Strategy and Management</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="about-us_creative-technology_square">
</div>
```